# Converting YYYYMMDD string to date in standard SQL / BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

I have this column called 'Date' that contains dates formatted this way: '20150101'.

I tried using sql substring, but when I run the query using 'date' function in sql, it doesn't work on the date format I have.

Here is the query I made:

```
SELECT (DATE ((SUBSTR(JOUR, 1, 4), 
               SUBSTR(JOUR, 5, 2), 
               SUBSTR(JOUR, 7, 2)))) As date 
FROM TABLE
```

Any idea? I couldn't find anything similar to this date format! I found one that uses the convert function but it's not in StandardSQL or BigQuery

Comment: Is this column a date column, or is it just text?

Comment: Hi, it's a string!

Comment: it's a string that looks like AAAAMMDD and I'm trying to convert it to a date that look like: AAAA-MM-DD

Comment: Possible duplicate of [STRING to DATE in BIGQUERY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44564887/string-to-date-in-bigquery)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

What about [PARSE_DATE](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/date_functions#parse_date) ?

```
SELECT PARSE_DATE("%Y%m%d", "20190101") as parsed;
```

For your table:

```
SELECT PARSE_DATE ("%Y%m%d", JOUR) As mydatecolumn from TABLE
```

Comment: Any reason why this wouldn't work and produces this message: Failed to parse input string "12102021"? Any help here is most appreciated!

Comment: "12102021" using "%Y%m%d" is "1210-20-21" and raises error because 20 is not a valid moth. Change mask format to "%m%d%Y" or whatever according to format you are using.