# How to insert string “dd/mm/yy hh:mm:ss” into datetime column in bigquery

Tags: sql, datetime, google-bigquery

I need to insert string “10/11/2019 12:34:45” into datetime column in bigquery , please advise any options ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [STRING to DATE in BIGQUERY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44564887/string-to-date-in-bigquery)

Comment: Yes string to date , which function will work ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

you can use

```
PARSE_DATETIME('%d/%m/%Y %T', datetime_col_as_string) datetime_col_as_datetime
```

for example, `SELECT PARSE_DATETIME('%d/%m/%Y %T', '10/11/2019 12:34:45')` produces datetime value as in below

```
Row datetime_col_as_datetime     
1   2019-11-10T12:34:45
```

Comment: Yes it worked for me , Thanks for that :)
New Issue - getting new error( String "Yes" is not converting to bool using cast ) any advise here ?

Comment: @HarshithSH I suggest that you accept his answer and create another question for this new error