# How to use regex to extract a date (in string format) without the 0

Tags: regex, date

Hi i am trying to use regex to detect a string which is basically a date format dd-MM-Y in where the month has a '0',and I want to select the string without the '0'.

i.e 13/03/2021  ----> 13/3/2021

however, if the month is 10,11,12, it will keep the full string without transforming it.

i.e
11/11/2020  ----> 11/11/2020

thanks

Comment: Regex alone isn't really the right tool for this.  What language are you using with your regex and data here?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Hi, I am asking this question for my colleague, he is actually using SQL trying to convert the date(in string format) to get rid of the 0. Here's the code he uses: CAST(REGEXP_REPLACE(CAST(Date AS STRING),'(?<=/)[0]','') AS STRING)

Comment: You should be using the built in text to date conversion function which your version of SQL _might_ have.  That being said, what is your version of SQL (e.g. MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle, etc.) ?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen we actually use google BigQuery. I suppose is Standard SQL?

Comment: See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44564887/string-to-date-in-bigquery

Comment: @Adamtky please read [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 2):

This works in [BigQuery](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/string_functions#regexp_replace).

```
REGEXP_REPLACE(CAST(Date AS STRING),'^(\d{2}\/)0(\d\/\d{4})$','\\1\\2')
```

Answer (score 0):

The following regex should help you match the dates by omitting the zeroes at the beginning of days and/or months.

```
0?([\d]{1,2})\/0?([\d]{1,2})\/([\d]{4})
```

You can reproduce the date in the required format by concatenating the capture groups 1, 2, and 3 with the delimiter of your choice. For example

```
$newDate = $1 . '/' . $2 . '/' . $3
```